# Getting window location of open apps via NodObjC

Tags: objective-c, node.js, macos, nodobjc

I've been messing around with the node.js module [NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) recently (very cool module btw), I threw together a simple module, [macmouse](https://github.com/Loknar/node-macmouse/), that gives you the ability to control your mouse through node.js, now I'm trying to fetch information on open windows via `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` (the idea is to do something fun using that information and the virtual mouse functionality).
I don't have much experience with Objective C but I stumbled upon an example of this in a blog post:

http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/monitoring-any-window-in-os-x/

I tested it out in Xcode,

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"

NSArray* windows = CFBridgingRelease(CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID));
NSLog(@"%@", windows);
```

and it prints out all the data I want and more, but now I'm stuck on how to do this using the NodObjC module.

Here's my go at it (using NodObjC v1.0.0):

```
var $ = require('NodObjC');
$.framework('Foundation');
$.framework('Cocoa');
var pool = $.NSAutoreleasePool('alloc')('init');

var windowList = $.CFBridgingRelease($.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo($.kCGWindowListOptionAll, $.kCGNullWindowID));

console.log(windowList);

pool('drain');
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/node_modules/ffi/lib/_foreign_function.js:55
  throw e
        ^
TypeError: error setting argument 0 - writePointer: Buffer instance expected as third argument
at Object.writePointer (/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:740:11)
at Object.set (/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:482:13)
at Object.alloc (/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:514:13)
at ForeignFunction.proxy (/Users/loknar/Desktop/node_robot/nodobjc_stuff/ffi/lib/_foreign_function.js:50:22)
at Function.unwrapper (/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/node_modules/NodObjC/lib/core.js:297:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/loknar/Desktop/nodobjc_stuff/listOfWindows.js:44:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

What's going wrong here? (I've also posted this question on the [NodObjC's issue page](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC/issues/48))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [version 1.0.1 of NodObjC](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC/blob/master/History.md#101--2015-04-09)